# Cannot upload 600 multiple documents in document library

Tags: document-library, file-upload

I am using sharepoint 2010. I have a document library. I have on my local machine 600 documents of tyoe .msg. These are email files. I try to upload all these 600 documents. But I see at the end there are only 400 documents uploaded. Is there some limit to upload multiple files?

Comment: Are you getting any error after uploading 400 files.

Comment: what is the total size (MB or GB) of all the documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx#ListLibrary

> 100 items per bulk operation
>
> The user interface allows a maximum of 100 items to be selected for
>   bulk operations

to get around this issue, open the document library in explorer view and upload that way.

goto the list page -> on the right hand side of the list at the top select the views drop down items and change it from the current view to 'explorer view' , this will then popup an explorer window just like on desktop that you can copy from your local machine to that location (copy/cut -> past or drag drop from one window(source) to the other window(target))